# The following assertion was thrown while running async test code: pumpAndSettle timed out

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, mocking

In flutter test i have error:

`The following assertion was thrown while running async test code:pumpAndSettle timed out`

My test script:

```
testWidgets('drawer widget test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

    await tester.runAsync(() async {
      when(operatorRepository.getCurrentSelectedOperator()).thenAnswer((_) async => operator);

      await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp(home: ScaffoldDrawerTest(operatorRepository)));
      expect(find.text('-1'), findsOneWidget);
      expect(find.text(''), findsOneWidget);
      expect(find.text('Warszawa'), findsNothing);
      await tester.tap(find.byType(IconButton).first);

      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      expect(find.text('Warszawa'), findsWidgets);
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();

      await tester.tap(find.byType(ListTile).at(2));
      expect(find.text('Warszawa'), findsNothing);
    });
  });
```

I try change `pumpAndSettle` to `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { await tester.pump(Duration(seconds: 1)); }`

but then i to receive error

```
  Actual: _TextFinder:<zero widgets with text "Warszawa" (ignoring offstage widgets)>
   Which: means none were found but some were expected
```

In ScaffoldDrawerTest i have Consumer and loading widget, when viewModel is loaded then i show another widgets when is widget text "Warszawa"